# How to get suspend when idle if no user logged in (lightdm)

Tags: suspend, lightdm, idle

I can't figure out how to get Ubuntu 11.10 to suspend when idle from a lightdm login screen. I've found methods to do this from gdm, but even those reference configuration files that aren't present in 11.10.

EXAMPLE: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1559941

I'm pulling my hair out, and I don't have much left!

Comment: Closed as too localized? It's got two upvotes and favourited twice so there's obviously some interest. Please reopen in case someone has an answer that they would like to provide.

Comment: I'll just answer in a comment for now because this question is currently closed. `sudo apt-get install sleepd` The default is 10 minutes of inactivity. You can change the defaults by editing /etc/defaults/sleepd. Set the PARAMS with `-u [number of seconds]`. Check out the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/sleepd.8.html) for more options.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I had given up on this and forgotten about it. Cheers!

Comment: The sleepd method was a huge win in our dormitory as we moved from single user to ldap. (The machines just hanged on lightdm for hours)

Comment: @RichardAyotte Please post your comment as an answer. The question is re-opened now :D

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Thanks. This question's popularity has grown since 2011 :)

Answer (score 1):

Install sleepd.

```
sudo apt-get install sleepd
```

By default, the system will go to sleep after 10 minutes of inactivity. Settings can be changed in `/etc/defaults/sleepd`. Set the PARAMS variable with `-u [number of seconds]` to set the number of seconds of inactivity that will cause the system to sleep. Check out the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sleepd.8.html) for more options.