# How can I get the computer to sleep while at the login screen? (No users logged in.)

Tags: 12.04, power-management, lightdm

I have my computer set to "Suspend when inactive for 30 minutes" in system settings. This function works fine if a user is logged in and does not do anything for 30 minutes. However, if all users are logged out and the computer is at the LightDM login screen, the computer will never go to sleep. How do I get the computer to sleep even if no users are logged in?

Comment: Similar unanswered question http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092631

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79647/how-to-get-suspend-when-idle-if-no-user-logged-in-lightdm). The second comment provides a good answer.