# Is it possible to put the computer into sleep mode while logged out in 14.04?

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, logout

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137082/how-can-i-get-the-computer-to-sleep-while-at-the-login-screen-no-users-logged), but that's tagged [12.04](/questions/tagged/12.04), and is unanswered, so i'm asking a new, more general, question.

If the computer is either *locked* or *logged out*, is it possible to put it to sleep? The laptop's hotkey for that doesn't work in either of these cases.

Ubuntu 14.04 with a default setup and multiple user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Open the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file in a text editor as root, for example,

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Add a line

> HandleLidSwitch=sleep

(make sure it's not commented out!),
Restart the systemd daemon with this command:

```
sudo restart systemd-logind
```

tell me if this fixed your issue. i found something similar here: [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)